# Using std::bind with member function, use object pointer or not for this argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

When using `std::bind` to bind a member function, the first argument is the objects `this` pointer. However it works passing the object both as a pointer and not.

See for example the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo
{
    void bar(int v) { std::cout << "foo::bar - " << v << '\n'; }
};

int main()
{
    foo my_foo;

    auto f1 = std::bind(&foo::bar, my_foo, 1);
    auto f2 = std::bind(&foo::bar, &my_foo, 2);

    f1();
    f2();
}
```

Both clang and GCC compiles this without complaints, and the result works for both binds:

```
foo::bar - 1
foo::bar - 2
```

I have been trying to wrap my head around the specification (section 20.8.9) but it's one of the places where it's far from clear to me.

Should only one be correct, or are both correct?

Comment: Scott's "overview of the new c++" slide 216, says two ways are both right. Except if my_foo is unique_pointer, need wrap with std::ref and it doesn't work with weak pointer

Comment: Scott's overview (on slide 221 in the latest deck) also says you can use `std::move` with a `unique_ptr` to transfer ownership into the callable object returned by `bind`. It doesn't work with `weak_ptr` because you can't dereference a `weak_ptr`

Comment: Be careful that in the f1 example, my_foo is copied. That would not work on non-copyable objects. If you delete the copy ctor of foo, this code would not compile.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen Nice for mentioning the difference.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Both are correct. 20.8.9.1.2 forwards to 20.8.2 to describe the requirements and the effect of your call to `bind`. 20.8.2 is:

> #### 20.8.2 Requirements [func.require]
>
> <sup>1</sup> Define *INVOKE*`(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> — `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
>
> — `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
>
> — `t1.*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
>
> — `(*t1).*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
>
> — `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.

The first two options allow both a reference and a pointer.

The important thing to notice here is that the wording does *not* limit you to plain pointers. You could use a `std::shared_ptr` or some other smart pointer to keep your instance alive while bound and it would still work with `std::bind` as `t1` is dereferenced, no matter what it is (given, of course, that it's possible).

Comment: Only the second (passing a pointer) method worked for me when my instance was a static variable.The first way caused each bind to act as if it was given another instance; that is, if f1 and f2 were run in succession, both bound using the first way, then the side effects of f1 on the static instance did not show when f2 was called

Comment: Ah I see now that I was copying my static instance to a new instance when I didn't pass a pointer. This is what I get for not following the rule of five

Answer (score 3):

To add to the correct answer (that both forms are allowed).

I think of the two binding options in analogy with function argument declaration, which may be "passed by value" or "passed by reference".

In the case of `f1` (aka passing `my_foo` "by value") the result doesn't "see" any changes made to `my_foo` past the binding point. This may not be desired especially if `my_foo` evolves. "By value" binding has an additional "cost" of (several) calls to a copy constructor.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference. As rytis put forward, passing by value doesn't see the changes made to my_foo. For example, in case my_foo is a class, passing by value doesn't see a change made to a member data of my_foo.