# Conformance of std::bind when providing a method pointer and an object of derived type

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, stdbind

This question is basically an aftermath of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15264126/2073257) answer I gave. I just realized that the wording in the standard seems to omit a few cases. Consider this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo
{
  void f(int v) { std::cout << v << std::endl; }
};

struct bar : foo {};

int main()
{
  bar obj;
  std::bind(&foo::f, obj, 1)();
}
```

The standard describes in 20.8.9.1.2 the effect of `std::bind` and what happens when it is invoked. It forwards to 20.8.2, the relevant part is:

> #### 20.8.2 Requirements [func.require]
>
> <sup>1</sup> Define *INVOKE*`(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> — `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
>
> — `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
>
> — `t1.*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
>
> — `(*t1).*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
>
> — `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.

Reading this, it seems to allow three cases for the first list item:

- `t1` is an object of type `T`
- or a reference to an object of type `T`
- or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`

but in my example, it is neither. It's a type derived from `T`, but without a reference. Shouldn't the above listed cases be:

- `t1` is an object of type `T`
- or an object of a type derived from `T`
- or a reference to an object of type `T`
- or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`

Of course, the same applies to the third list item in 20.8.2.

**Question 1:** As both GCC and Clang accept my code, I wonder if this is a defect report against the standard or if I'm just reading it wrong.

**Question 2:** With multiple/virtual inheritance, even if a type is derived from `T`, it might not simply be possible to call `(t1.*f)(...)` on it, right? Is that also something I should be concerned about or does the standard define "derived from" clearly in the given context?

Comment: I'm not really sure when the "object of type T" case is needed, and why the reference case doesn't cover it. There _is_ a defect in that wording though, see [LWG 2219](http://cplusplus.github.com/LWG/lwg-active.html#2219). I should find out when/why it's needed and if it's needed for ref wrappers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paragraph 20.8.9.1.3 of the C++11 Standard defines the effects of calling `std::bind()` in terms of the `INVOKE()` *pseudo-function* this way:

> *Returns*: A forwarding call wrapper `g` with a weak result type (20.8.2). The effect of `g(u1, u2, ..., uM)` shall be `INVOKE (fd, std::forward<V1>(v1), std::forward<V2>(v2), ..., std::forward<VN>(vN),
>   result_of<FD cv & (V1, V2, ..., VN)>::type)`

Notice that the call to `std::forward<>` will always return a **reference type**, be it an lvalue reference or an rvalue reference. Per Paragraphs 20.2.3/1-2, in fact:

> `template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept;`
>
> `template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept;`
>
> *Returns*: `static_cast<T&&>(t)`

Therefore, the `INVOKE` pseudo-function (watch out: not the `bind()` function!) will be invoked with references here, and this is supported by the definition you quoted.

I believe the Standard itself never makes use of the `INVOKE()` pseudo-function (which is just some internal formalism) with objects (not references to object) of a type derived from `T`.

However, this doesn't meant that you cannot invoke `std::bind()` or other functions whose definition is in turn given in terms of `INVOKE()` with an object (not a reference to an object) of a type derived from `T`.

Comment: That seems about right, thanks. Had to read through 20.8.9.1.3/10 to figure out what V1/v1 ... VN/vN actually is. That's certainly not the easiest part of the standard :)