# std::bind of class member function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
        int get(int n) { return 5+n; }
};

int main()
{
        Foo foo;
        auto L = std::bind(&Foo::get, &foo, 3);

        std::cout << L() << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Seems that this:

```
auto L = std::bind(&Foo::get, &foo, 3);
```

is equivalento to:

```
auto L = std::bind(&Foo::get, foo, 3);
```

Why?

Comment: It's not. One binds a pointer, the other binds a *copy*.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can also pass a smart pointer (any type that implements `operator->` to return a `foo*`) as the second argument. Try it with a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264003/using-stdbind-with-member-function-use-object-pointer-or-not-for-this-argumen 
Though I like both answers...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`std::bind()` accepts its arguments **by value**. This means that in the first case you are passing a *pointer* by value, resulting in the copy of a pointer. In the second case, you are passing an object of type `foo` by value, resulting in a copy of an object of type `Foo`.

As a consequence, in the second case the evaluation of the expression `L()` causes the member function `get()` to be invoked on a *copy* of the original object `foo`, which may or may not be what you want.

This example illustrates the difference (forget the violation of the Rule of Three/Rule of Five, this is just for illustration purposes):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Foo
{
    int _x;

    Foo(int x) : _x(x) { }

    Foo(Foo const& f) : _x(f._x)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo(Foo const&)" << std::endl;
    }

    int get(int n) { return _x + n; }
};

int main()
{
   Foo foo1(42);

   std::cout << "=== FIRST CALL ===" << std::endl;
   auto L1 = std::bind(&Foo::get, foo1, 3);
   foo1._x = 1729;
   std::cout << L1() << std::endl; // Prints 45

   Foo foo2(42);

   std::cout << "=== SECOND CALL ===" << std::endl;
   auto L2 = std::bind(&Foo::get, &foo2, 3);
   foo2._x = 1729;
   std::cout << L2() << std::endl; // Prints 1732
}
```

[***Live example***](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a26e3c4ba76171db).

If, for any reason, you don't want to use the pointer form, you can use [`std::ref()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) to prevent a copy of the argument from being created:

```
auto L = std::bind(&Foo::get, std::ref(foo), 3);
```

Answer (score 4):

They are not the same. The generic function binder `std::bind` **copies** it's arguments. In the case of `std::bind(&Foo::get,&foo,3)`, the *pointer* is copied, but when you call the bound object it still applies to the original `foo` object. In `std::bind(&Foo::get,foo,3)` the object `foo` is copied, and the later call applies to the bound copy, not to the original object.

You can test this by using a member function that accesses internal state of the object, bind the object in both ways, change the original object and see how the results differ.