# Issue with binding non static function to callback

Tags: c++

I can't bind a non-static member function to a callback.
I have to bind the `test2` class member function `here()` to `test1` member `callBack` which is a `std::function`, but I could not find way to do this. Anyone can suggest me if you have any idea.

Show in code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class test1{
public:
    typedef std::function<void()> callback_function_t;
    callback_function_t callBack;
    void setCallback(callback_function_t _callBackfn){
        callBack = std::move(_callBackfn);
    }

    void check(void){
        callBack();
    }
};

class test2{
public:
    void here(){
        cout << "safsafsdf" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    test1 t1;
    test2 t2;
    t1.setCallback(t2.here); // Can't Works
    return 0;
}
```

must be set in test1 callback.

Comment: check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016112/stdbind-of-class-member-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that when creating the `std::function` you have also to provide the instance of the class the member function has to be invoked on. The other answer uses `std::bind`, which is a possible solution.
I would suggest using a lambda function as an alternative, for readability:

```
t1.setCallback([&t2](){t2.here();});
```

Note that here you are capturing `t2` as a reference, so you must ensure that `t2` is alive when `t1` uses the callback.

Alternatively you can capture by value (making a copy)

```
t1.setCallback([t2]() mutable {t2.here();});
```

and you need the `mutable` keyword to allow the call of a non-const qualified member function

Finally you can also move `t2` inside the lambda, avoiding a copy

```
t1.setCallback([t2 = std::move(t2)]() mutable {t2.here();});
```

this is the generalized capture, available from C++14. In your specific example using the `std::move` will hardly make any difference, but in general, if the object is complex, this might be of use.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you're using for binding the `this` pointer to `t1` isn't correct. You can't simply write `t2.here` in order to get a function which, when called, is essentially the same as `t2.here()`.

One possible solution is to bind the `this` object via `std::bind()`, e.g.

```
t1.setCallback(std::bind(&test2::here, t2));
```

But keep in mind, this creates a copy of `t2` inside the function object finally stored inside `t2.callBack`. Modifications to `t2` don't affect `t1.callBack`. If you're sure `t1` always outlives `t2`, you can also create a reference

```
    t1.setCallback(std::bind(&test2::here, std::ref(t2)));
```